# Haskell: Couldn't match expected type ‘(a, b0)’ with actual type ‘(a, b, h)’

Tags: haskell

My code:

```
g :: (a, b, h) -> (c, d, i) -> ((a, c))
g x y = ((fst x, fst y))
```

Why does it print the following errors?:

```
ax.hs:11:15: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘(a, b0)’
                  with actual type ‘(a, b, h)’
    • In the first argument of ‘fst’, namely ‘x’
      In the expression: fst x
      In the expression: ((fst x, fst y))
    • Relevant bindings include
        x :: (a, b, h) (bound at ax.hs:11:3)
        g :: (a, b, h) -> (c, d, i) -> (a, c) (bound at ax.hs:11:1)
   |
11 | g x y = ((fst x, fst y))
   |               ^

ax.hs:11:22: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘(c, b1)’
                  with actual type ‘(c, d, i)’
    • In the first argument of ‘fst’, namely ‘y’
      In the expression: fst y
      In the expression: ((fst x, fst y))
    • Relevant bindings include
        y :: (c, d, i) (bound at ax.hs:11:5)
        g :: (a, b, h) -> (c, d, i) -> (a, c) (bound at ax.hs:11:1)
   |
11 | g x y = ((fst x, fst y))
```

Please help. I'm not sure why this is happening. How do I fix it? Thank you

Comment: `fst :: (a,b) -> a`. You need something like an `fst3`, which would work on triples, but that's not in the Prelude. Pretty easy to write yourself, though.

Comment: so fst works with only two element tuples?

Comment: `fst` only applies to pairs (2-tuples)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**`fst :: (a, b) -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fst) only works for **2**-tuples, not tuples with a different arity than 2.

You can use pattern matching to obtain the first item of the 3-tuple, and personally I would use pattern matching for the second tuple as well, since this is - in my opinion - a more transparent syntax:

```
g :: (a, b, h) -> (c, d, i) -> (a, c)
g (x, _, _) (y, _, _) = (x, y)
```

Note that `((a, c))` is the same as `(a, c)`, so we can remove the extra parenthesis.